# What parts of Roslyn can you use with VS 2013?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild, roslyn

I want to build a C# app that uses the Roslyn NuGet packages. I have Visual Studio 2013. Things were going fine until I hit a ReflectionTypeLoadException looking for Microsoft.Build version 14, which I take it comes with VS 2015 CTP (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25504951/msbuildworkspace-create-throws-exception)).

My question is, how far can you get with Roslyn without running into this issue? Do you just need to avoid using the MSBuildWorkspace class? What are the alternatives? Is it possible to download and use the Microsoft.Build assembly from 2015 while still using the 2013 IDE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to download the MSBuild 14 tools from http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9863815